# have an svg file and want to serve with css but not sure and if i apply any color to it, will it take it and even also resizing

Tags: html, css

i have an `svg` file big enough and its back, i want to make it blue and have it server through css, how should i do it

any clue

i am following a `tutorial` on website but bit unsure

```
https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/
```

i am not sure how can  i se the svg file as an icon in css, any idea please guide

i tried serving the file using the background  : url, but it does not load, how can i convert the svg to data-uri so i can server it right away instead of calling the svg file

and if i use data-uri, will it implement other techniques of color change etc etc

Answer (score 1):

You can also render the svg inside the your html file like

```
<div>
  <svg>
    ...
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: i managed to do in css, but now the fill does not work, need to change the color but not happening `icon-svg-process {
    content: url("/inprocess.svg");
    fill: #94d31b !important;
    stroke: #fc0;`

Comment: @VueJS inside the svg change the fill value to 'inherit' then, in your css file try: 
div svg {
  fill: red;
}
and let me know if that worked!